# How to stacically compile DBD::mysql and move the files on a shared hosting where i have my own perl installation

Tags: mysql, perl, ubuntu, static, redhat

1. I have downloaded and installed locally on my Ubuntu ActiveState Perl(ActivePerl-5.14.1.1401-x86_64-linux-glibc-2.3.5-294969.tar.gz).
2. I did "~$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev"
3. I downloaded from CPAN [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql-4.019/)
4. I read  [INSTALL.html](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.019/INSTALL.html)
   And here is my problem:
   I am not sure how to compile a statically linked DBD::mysql which i can copy from my local ActivePerl installation to the same perl instalaltion but on my shared hosting provider mashine.
   Note that the uploaded via ftp(no ssh there) perl directory structure works on the shared hosting (also x86_64-linux) after changing executable file permissions in ActivePerl/bin/ directory.
   My CGI scripts run well under mod_cgi and mod_fast_cgi on the shared hosting.
   I tried the advises in the installation document([INSTALL.html#source_installation](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.019/INSTALL.html)) but no luck.
   On another shared hosting with i586 Active Perl DBD::mysql just works because I first installed it locally using PPM and then uploaded via FTP. However there is no x86_64 PPM package provided by ActiveState.
   Can sonmebody provide the magick spells for the commandline(ubuntu 11.04), something like:

   ```
   me@mine:~$ mkdir /tmp/mysql-static
   me@mine:~$ cp /usr/lib/libmysqlclien* /tmp/mysql-static
   me@mine:~$ cd ~/install/Perl/DBD-mysql-4.019/
   me@mine:~/install/Perl/DBD-mysql-4.019$ perl Makefile.PL --libs="-L/tmp/mysql-static -lmysqlclient"
   me@mine:~/install/Perl/DBD-mysql-4.019$ make    
   me@mine:~/install/Perl/DBD-mysql-4.019$ make install
   ```

...
 ...hm :D seems it worked this time, but anyway I wrote all of the above... it might be useful to others. I will upload later today on the shared hosting to see if it works.

Comment: Also a quick advice on how to make PPMs may help. Thanks!

Comment: Are such kind of posts accepted on SO? This looks more like a blog entry.

Comment: is this bad? Imagine that I have no one to share/ask?

Comment: It's not inherently bad but if everyone starts to write little howto's, the purpose of SO will shift from a collaborative Q&A site to a publicly postable tutorial site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.
The only thing that one has to be aware is when using it on the shared hosting. You should connect via TCP instead of via Unix socket:

```
$dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306";
$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password);
```

As written in the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ecapttofu/DBD-mysql-4.019/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#Class_Methods):

*To connect to a MySQL server on localhost using TCP/IP, you must specify the hostname as 127.0.0.1 (with the optional port).*